# CheckboxModel to get checked All value in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have used check box model in the grid panel and it can Checked All. i have got the value when it is checked or unchecked selected column. like this

```
var selModel = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
    checkOnly: true,
    listeners: {
        deselect: function(model, record, index) {
            id = record.get('id');
            alert(id);
        },
        select: function(model, record, index) {
            id = record.get('id');
            alert(id);
        }
    }
})
```

but how to get value when I click checked all?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`selectionchange`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-event-selectionchange) event:

> Fired after a selection change has occurred
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> this: `Ext.selection.Model`
>   selected: `Ext.data.Model[]` The selected records
>   eOpts: Object The options object passed to `Ext.util.Observable.addListener`.

Alternatively you can use the [`getSelection()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-method-getSelection) method in your `select` event:

> Returns an array of the currently selected records.